# The thought of something

Tags: grammar

There are two sentences with "thought of",

> Oh, Paul, even the thought of you in all that danger, it was just too
> much.

> She’s the single most beautiful girl I’ve ever seen, and the thought
> of touching her like this and not **being** able to see her ... — is
> torture.

The first one doesn't contain "being" but the second does. Why?

> ... even the thought of you being in all that danger, ...

Does this sentence sound natural?

Comment: Yes, the second sentence contains the word _being_, but not in the same phrase as _thought of_. There is no rule that says _thought of_ has to be followed by _being_. You could include it in your first sentence if you wanted to, but it isn't essential.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

'Oh, Paul, even the thought of you in all that danger, it was just too much.'

'Oh, Paul, even the thought of you being in all that danger, it was just too much.'

To summarise after @Kate Bunting's comments, both examples are fine.

I personally prefer shorter versions in general.